matching ceiling knockdown texture?
After installing pancake lighting, I need to match the existing ceiling texture.  Anyone know how to replicate this texture? Is it knockdown using a lot of mud?


I've seen wallpaper that had something very much like this kind of texture on it. May be worth a look if you can find something like that.

You have a "knockdown" or lace ceiling.  It can be repaired with some patience.
The texture is made by application of varying drops or globs of drywall compound  to the surface, then wiping over them with a taping knife or a Knockdown knife.  Thus the name "knockdown" as you are knocking down the tops of the globs and spreading it out.
The size and number of the globs, and the pressure you use when knocking them down give the resultant texture. It takes some experimentation and practice to match an existing texture, but it can be done and the entire ceiling does not need to be redone. (Depending on the size of the repair area.)
There are spray cans of the texture that can be purchased from almost anywhere that sells paint.  The spray is adjustable and will produce random varied globs on the surface it is sprayed on. You still need to knock it down.  For very small areas, (less than a square foot) I have just dabbed drywall compound on the surface using a sponge or a rag or a brush or even my fingers. Then knocked it down with a flat tool, (taping or knockdown knife.)
However you choose to repair the surface , it must dry for about 24 hours and then be painted.  matching the ceiling paint is another issue and another question.

Would this be stomp knockdown?

Stomp usually has a more uniform pattern. Something that is directional and repeated. However almost anything can be done by combining techniques.

For a new house, unpainted spray-on popcorn ceilings are installed much more quickly and cheaply than taped, sanded, and painted drywall, and they look much nicer for prospective buyers. But when they eventually get damaged, they are impossible to repair without looking like they have been repaired unless you do the entire ceiling.
The ceiling in the photo looks like it's been painted, so you'll also have to match the colour and gloss (or repaint the whole thing).
Some companies specialize in removing spray-on ceilings and turning them into standard drywall ceiling.
There are home repair products available, but they never quite work as well as advertised.
The good news though is that even though the repair is still visible, after a while you'll stop noticing it.
